# Android Studio/react-native project: Unable to remove gradle error: Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, opencv, gradle

I am trying to add OpenCV functionality to my react-native project and following online tutorials for the same and i am not able to resolve the gradle build error.

[My project structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2BtL.png)

The Android gradle build file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

The opencv gradle build file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def openCVersionName = "4.5.1"
def openCVersionCode = ((4 * 100 + 5) * 100 + 1) * 10 + 0

println "OpenCV: " +openCVersionName + " " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26

        versionCode openCVersionCode
        versionName openCVersionName

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                targets "opencv_jni_shared"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
        }
        release {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
            java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

I have checked the gradle plugin(4.1.0) and gradle(6.5) version and they are compatible.
Tried building with gradle wrapper(6.5) and local gradle(6.8) as well but still getting the same error.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Solved, silly mistake from my side.
opencv module had to be imported in the android directory instead of the root directory